# Regex returning <_s instead of decimal value

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python and regex to try and search for text.  Given the string within a text file:

```
line = (<layerThickness> 0.58 </layerThickness>)
```

I am trying to assign 0.58 to  variable L, however the output is consistently, "<_s" rather than the decimal value. This is what I have been trying:

```
L = re.search(r"([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)", line)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure? When I run that code here, `L.group(1)` is '0.58'. can you post actual results from the interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you just need to call the `.group()` method:

```
import re
line = '(<layerThickness> 0.58 </layerThickness>)'
L = re.search(r"([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)", line).group(0)
print(L)
```

yields

```
0.58
```

Comment: This works!  I actually tried the group method earlier but it didn't work because I was indexing from 1 (I usually program in Matlab, which indexes from 1 so I was trying group(1)) and it kept raising an error, so I tried accessing it without the group.  Noob mistake. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Why, this is correct! Here is what I see:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '(<layerThickness> 0.58 </layerThickness>)'
>>> L = re.search(r"([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)", line)
>>> L.group()
'0.58'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is fine, you're just not realizing that re.search, IF it finds a match, returns a re.Match object.  That's because an re.Match object doesn't necessarily have only one group.  You need to use the re.Match.group or re.Match.groups methods to return the actual value of the group your regular expression finding.

```
>>> line = '(<layerThickness> 0.58 </layerThickness>)'
>>> L = re.search(r"([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)", line)
>>> print L
_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100499dc8>
>>> print L.group()
0.58
```

Note, by the way, that the group is still a string, NOT an integer / float, you'll still need to cast it to an integer / float to use it in math.

Note also that L might be None if your line did not include a match at all, so you'll need to test for that in production code.